# How to stop Toast from not being resolved

Tags: java, android-studio, android-toast

I just came accros a very weird error while I was on Android studio. I ran my app on my phone on android studio and it worked fine. Only to find out an error appeared immediately after the launch. a
All the toast in my project saying Can not resolve toast. I thought maybe the import widget was missing but is not. When I run the apps it runs but the error is just still there.  This error appears to affect all of my project in android studio. Please help guys.

`Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show(),.`

Comment: invalidate the cache and restart Android Studio. then reimport the gradle. this might fix

Comment: I have already restarted and invalidated the cache. What do you mean by reimport grade?

Comment: reimport gradle project

Comment: Already done that too. Seeing as this affects all my project, not just one project I think it has to do with Android studio itself not project.

Comment: can you share your gradle version and build tool versions

Comment: are you importing from `import android.widget.Toast` this package. if yes are getting error on this import?

Comment: I use android gradle plugin 3.2.1 with Gradle  version 4.6 and a buildToolsVersion "30.0.0". Yes i am importing `import android.widget.Toast` and I am also getting an error on the import statement.